# Grant a non-admin right to terminate processes on a Server 2012

Tags: process, windows-server-2012, kill

Is there a way to grant a non-admin user the rights to terminate/kill a process on a Server 2012 without making them local admin?

I know it's an odd question, but please, if anyone has a suggestion, let me know.

Comment: This could definitely cause a lot of trouble - You shouldn't have any reason to do this other than to cause trouble. So I doubt anyone in here will help you with this. If you actually are the administrator of the server you should give some more information as to what your problem is.

Comment: Is it possible to grant the User group this permission: Yes; The permission extends to any process though, this means a user in this user group, will be able to end any process.

Comment: I'm a domain admin. The request comes from a super user who monitors a process on an application server, where a process from their application hangs from time to time and I haven't been able to find a way to do this other than granting him local admin access on the server which I of course won't do.